# Excel - create new cell with column title if other cells have 'X' in them

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with columns like so:

```
------------------
|Ultra |OTM |OTR |
------------------
|X     |    |X   |
|      |    |X   |
|X     |X   |X   |
|X     |X   |    |
|      |    |X   |
------------------
```

And I need to create a new column with '|' separated column titles for each 'X' in that row:

```
-----------------------------------
|Ultra |OTM |OTR |Interests       |
-----------------------------------
|X     |    |X   |Ultra|OTR       |
|      |    |X   |OTR             |
|X     |X   |X   |Ultra|OTM|OTR   |
|X     |X   |    |Ultra|OTM       |
|      |    |X   |OTR             |
-----------------------------------
```

What;s the formula I need for this new column please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(A2="x",A$1&"|","")&IF(B2="x",B$1&"|","")&IF(C2="x",C$1,"")
```

copied down to suit though may give one too many pipes, at the end.

A similar approach without a 'spare' pipe is rather lenghthier!:

```
=IF(RIGHT(IF(A2="x",A$1&"|","")&IF(B2="x",B$1&"|","")&IF(C2="x",C$1,""),1)="|",LEFT(IF(A2="x",A$1&"|","")&IF(B2="x",B$1&"|","")&IF(C2="x",C$1,""),LEN(IF(A2="x",A$1&"|","")&IF(B2="x",B$1&"|","")&IF(C2="x",C$1,""))-1),IF(A2="x",A$1&"|","")&IF(B2="x",B$1&"|","")&IF(C2="x",C$1,""))
```